# Using Shortcode Result In Custom HTML Block (Using Google Sheet JQuery Result As NumScroller data-max)

Tags: plugins, theme-development, shortcode, html, genesis-theme-framework

After creating a Shortcode that aquires google sheet data and then getting a JQuery plugin (numscroll) working that makes numbers scroll up to a certain number when displayed I am having difficulty combining these two solutions into a single "Custom HTML Block".

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<h2 class="has-text-align-center"><strong>

<span class="numscroller" data-min="1" data-max=[get_sheet_value location="'Summary Page'!C3"] data-delay="5" data-increment="10">0</span>

</strong></h2>
```

Which for some reason results in the default "data-min" value (**1**) being displayed (possibly due to the time it takes to get the result?) rather than the correct value.

I've also tried "do_shortcode" but that doesn't change the results.

```
<h2 class="has-text-align-center"><strong>

<span class="numscroller" data-min="1" data-max=do_shortcode('[get_sheet_value location="'Summary Page'!C3"]') data-delay="5" data-increment="10">0</span>

</strong></h2>
```

My attempt consists of two parts, part one (which is the shortcode):

```
[get_sheet_value location="'Summary Page'!C3"]
```

which calls this function to get the value of a single cell:

```
/**
 * Aquiring google sheet data (David Stockdale)
 * Shortcode should be something like this: [get_sheet_value location="'Summary Page'!C3"]
 */
function sheet_value_shortcode($atts) {
    $API = 'XXX';
    $google_spreadsheet_ID = 'XXX';
    $api_key = esc_attr( $API);

    $location = $atts['location'];
    $get_cell = new WP_Http();
    $cell_url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$google_spreadsheet_ID/values/$location?&key=$api_key";  
    $cell_response = $get_cell -> get( $cell_url);
    $json_body = json_decode($cell_response['body'],true);  
    $cell_value = $json_body['values'][0][0];
    return $cell_value;
}

add_shortcode('get_sheet_value', 'sheet_value_shortcode');
```

And part two (which works in a "Custom HTML Block"):

```
<span class="numscroller" data-min="1" data-max="100" data-delay="5" data-increment="10">0</span>
```

Which once the script is added:

```
/**
 * Adds script (David Stockdale).
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
/**
 * Adds script for NumScroller (David Stockdale).
 */
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'numscroller-1.0', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
        '/lib/numscroller-1.0.js', // this is the location of your script file.
        array( 'jquery' ), // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
        '', //Not needed with Beans, Required with Genisis.
        true //Not needed with Beans, Required with Genisis.
    );
}
```

Calls this JQuery Plugin:

```
/**
* jQuery scroroller Plugin 1.0
* 
* http://www.tinywall.net/
* 
* Developers: Arun David, Boobalan
* Copyright (c) 2014 
*/
jQuery(document).ready((function($){
    $(window).on("load",function(){
        $(document).scrollzipInit();
        $(document).rollerInit();
    });
    $(window).on("load scroll resize", function(){
        $('.numscroller').scrollzip({
            showFunction    :   function() {
                                    numberRoller($(this).attr('data-slno'));
                                },
            wholeVisible    :     false,
        });
    });
    $.fn.scrollzipInit=function(){
        $('body').prepend("<div style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:0;height:0;' id='scrollzipPoint'></div>" );
    };
    $.fn.rollerInit=function(){
        var i=0;
        $('.numscroller').each(function() {
            i++;
           $(this).attr('data-slno',i); 
           $(this).addClass("roller-title-number-"+i);
        });        
    };
    $.fn.scrollzip = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            showFunction    : null,
            hideFunction    : null,
            showShift       : 0,
            wholeVisible    : false,
            hideShift       : 0,
        }, options);
        return this.each(function(i,obj){
            $(this).addClass('scrollzip');
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.showFunction ) ){
                if(
                    !$(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    ($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.showShift)>($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))&&
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))<($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.showShift)
                ){
                    $(this).addClass('isShown');
                    settings.showFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.hideFunction ) ){
                if(
                    $(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    (($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.hideShift)<($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))||
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))>($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.hideShift))
                ){
                    $(this).removeClass('isShown');
                    settings.hideFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            return this;
        });
    };
    function numberRoller(slno){
            var min=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-min');
            var max=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-max');
            var timediff=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-delay');
            var increment=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-increment');
            var numdiff=max-min;
            var timeout=(timediff*1000)/numdiff;
            //if(numinc<10){
                //increment=Math.floor((timediff*1000)/10);
            //}//alert(increment);
            numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout);

    }
    function numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout){//alert(slno+"="+min+"="+max+"="+increment+"="+timeout);
        if(min<=max){
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(min);
            min=parseInt(min)+parseInt(increment);
            setTimeout(function(){numberRoll(eval(slno),eval(min),eval(max),eval(increment),eval(timeout))},timeout);
        }else{
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(max);
        }
    }
}));
```

Both of these solutions work on their own, how can I combine them?

Also sorry if the solution turns out to be something really obvious or this should be posted somewhere else, but I just started using WordPress like 2 weeks ago and I'm still getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a plugin for this:
https://davidstockdalescrapcode.co.uk/my-plugins